# ClosedXML: Export To Excel not downloading the File MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, closedxml, kingsoft

I have a `List<T>`, which I convert to a Datatable and then export that Datatable to Excel via [Kingsoft-Spreadsheets](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/spreadsheets-free.html) using ClosedXML library.

However, for some reason the code is not working and the sheet is not getting downloaded. I am getting strange symbolic screen on my MVC view. I have attached the image for reference. Any help much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was using ajax post back on Export Excel button click,there was no page postback.Acutally full page post back is required. I just added window.location.href with respective controller and action method and voila..its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Excel file is created correctly but your browser tries to open it like a plain text file. Set the content type and the content disposition header for the response correctly like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myName);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; // or "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

For a full working code example see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296136/download-file-with-closedxml?rq=1) and its answers.

Comment: Sir,I added the contentType and AddHeader values as above already, despite that the error persists.

Comment: DataTable dtq = GetDT(List<T>);
MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
wb.Worksheets.Add(dtq);
 Response.Clear(); Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HelloWorld.xlsx");
Response.Buffer = true;
wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}

Comment: I tried different code snippets;yet no success,all the content is rendering to browser,any suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid to call ajax :

```
function ExportSPReport() {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("ExportSPReport", "Report")';
    @*$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ExportSPReport", "Report")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                //$("#downloadFile").attr("href", data);
                //document.getElementById('downloadFile').click();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
            }
        });
    }*@
}
```

Comment: Don't use ajax call,use window location