# Return Excel File from WebAPI ASPNetCore

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to create the WebAPI which will return an Excel file by using ClosedXML Library.

It's all working fine, if I return the FileStreamResult.  But if I changed it to HttpResponseMessage as discussed here [Web API Return A File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/microsoft-web-api-return-a-file-use-byte), I couldn't download a file or see the content anymore and getting JSON string.

I would like to know how I could extract the File Content from this HttpResponseMessage.

I tested in browser or PostMan tool and all I got back is JSON String:

```
{
      "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
      },
      "content": {
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Disposition",
            "value": [
              "attachment; filename=ERSheet.xlsx"
            ]
          },
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": [
              "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode": 200,
      "reasonPhrase": "OK",
      "headers": [],
      "requestMessage": null,
      "isSuccessStatusCode": true
    }
```

My Code is as follow:

```
[HttpGet("ERSheet2")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ER_GenerateWBLWorksheet2()
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

            var SheetNames = new List<string>() { "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20" };

            foreach (var sheetname in SheetNames)
            {
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetname);

                worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = sheetname;
            }

            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "ERSheet.xlsx";
            return result;
        }
```

**Updated**

This one is different from this question [Download file with ClosedXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296136) because I mentioned that I already made it work by using 'FileStreamResult'.  I am asking this because of this comment "Better to return HttpResponseMessage with StreamContent inside of it." made in this thread [Web API Return A File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125535/microsoft-web-api-return-a-file-use-byte).  So, trying to use HttpResponseMessage in .Net Core and didn't know that it doesn't support anymore as Darin's answer.

Comment: This ResponseMessage doesn't have any content. I mean content of  Excel file. Or am I not right?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.  My ResponseMessage does not contain any content or HttpResponseMessage cannot be used to hold any content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file with ClosedXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296136/download-file-with-closedxml)

Comment: First, your JSON String doesn't have any content  of Excel file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API running on .NET Core doesn't support `HttpResponseMessage` anymore. So basically it tries to serialize the instance of this object that you are returning to JSON (as if it was a simple view model of yours). There are some [`compatibility shim hacks`](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) which you could use but in general I would recommend you using the more idiomatic approach - return an `IActionResult` instance from your action:

```
[HttpGet("ERSheet2")]
public IActionResult ER_GenerateWBLWorksheet2()
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();

        var SheetNames = new List<string>() { "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20" };

        foreach (var sheetname in SheetNames)
        {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetname);

            worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = sheetname;
        }

        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return this.File(
            fileContents: stream.ToArray(), 
            contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 

            // By setting a file download name the framework will
            // automatically add the attachment Content-Disposition header
            fileDownloadName: "ERSheet.xlsx"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it must be the main reason.  I am trying to return it in HttpResponse coz of this line in another answer.
"Better to return HttpResponseMessage with StreamContent inside of it."  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but this answer is about ASP.NET Web API running on the full .NET framework, not for .NET Core.

Comment: How do you see whether the question is related to .Net core or Standard .Net?  I couldn't find those hashtags anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using:

response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer());

However, I'm having a problem getting this to work for Angular2.  It DOES work with Angular1.

Comment: Its not clear how this answer is relevant. The question doesn't mention using Angular. But maybe you see something I don't and can help the Asker clarify the question?